# Java/C# inside Web Application/React

Tags: java, c#, html, canvas, webassembly

I am developing a 2d game for the web. For that, I intend to use a "canvas" and render my game from there. For better performance, I would like to use languages like Java or C #. After research, I found out that this was possible through WebAssembly. So, my questions are: how do I create a webassembly file (using C # or java) and how do I add the html that it returns to a React page.

Answer (score 0):

Webassembly wouldn't  necessarily be faster than JS when i comes to rendering because Webassembly doesn't have direct access to the DOM. Instead you have to create "bindings" from javascript to your WebAssembly code.

So the way you can connect Webassembly to a `canvas` is using an `ArrayBuffer` which Webassembly would write to, and javascript would read from and put the data in the canvas.
But the rendering will still be done through the javascript thread. unless you are using the same instance of `ArrayBuffer` to pass data, I don't think it will be any faster.

[Example of rendering to canvas from WebAssembly](https://www.hellorust.com/demos/canvas/index.html)

I know that you can use [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor), this C# framework allows you to execute C# code in the browser (It sends the entire .NET runtime to the client tho), and it compiles to WebAssembly